# How can I get variable n1 to perform the calculations under the last while loop and print the number of conversions (variable: noc)?

Tags: c

My issue is that it is recognizing the variables and requesting user input for both `n1` and `n2`, but once I enter both values I want it to evaluate `n1` (the starting value) and do the `/ 2` or `* 3 + 1` depending on if it's even or odd, reach 1 and then print the number of calculations.

Here is my code so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void points(void);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    points();
}
void points(void)
{
    int n1, n2;
    int noc = 0;
    printf("Enter a starting point: ");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    while (n1 < 2 || n1 > 1000)
    {
        printf("Please enter an integer 2-1000: ");
        scanf("%d", &n1);
    }
    printf("Enter an ending point: ");
    scanf("%d", &n2);
    while (n2 < n1 || n2 > 10000)
    {
        printf("Please enter an integer bigger than the start point and <= 10000: ");
        scanf("%d", &n2);
    }
    while (n1 != 1)
    {
        if (n1 % 2 == 0)
        {
            n1 = n1 / 2;
        }
        else (n1 % 2 == 1);
        {
            n1 = n1 * 3 + 1;
        }
        noc++;
    }
    printf("%d: %d", n1, noc);
}
```

Comment: Start your code on the line after ``` to avoid missing any part.

Answer (score 0):

The `else` portion of an `if ... else` statement does not take a condition. We already know the `else` is being done if the `if` condition is false—there is no need to restate the opposite of that condition.

In `else (n1 % 2 == 1);`, because you also have a semicolon there, the compiler things you want `(n1 % 2 == 1)` to be a statement, not a condition to the else. So it compiles that as the statement for the `else`, and the `if ... else` statement ends there. The block with `n1 = (n1 * 3) + 1;` after it is a separate statement and is always executed, regardless of the `if` or `else`.

Additionally, declare `points` before `main` by inserting the declaration `void points(void);`.

Turn on warnings in your compiler and pay attention to them. The compiler should have warned you that `points` was not declared and that the result of the expression `(n1 % n2 == 1)` was not used.

Answer (score 0):

This line `else (n1 % 2 == 1);` must be `else if (n1 % 2 == 1)` or simply `else`.